# How to make an effect last for only a certain amount of time

Tags: after-effects, editing

I feel like I've done 50 google searches now, and still haven't figured this out. I am new to after effects, and have been unable to make my effects last for a certain amount of the timeline.

For example:

> I want the effect to start, and then stop a while later on the
>   timeline.

I've pressed every button and done every google search to try and figure that out. I've also done every stack exchange search.

> How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to do this is to [animate](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/setting-selecting-deleting-keyframes.html) the effect. Whatever effect values you are altering, those need to be set to zero or null result value 1 frame before your intended start time. In the next frame set it to the desired value for the effect. Set a key for the desired value at the last frame of your intended range. Then set a key for the zero/null value the next frame.

The crude way to do this is to split the layer at the start frame and end frame <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+D</kbd>. And remove/disable the effect on the layers outside the effect range.